# How to compare two pixel colors

Tags: java, compare

I am writing a program that opens a program, and waits for it to load. While it loads, there's a loading bar in the middle and the rest of the screen is black.

What I want it to do is check the color at, let's say, 1200 and 300, save it as a variable, then check to see if both are the same color every 1 seccond, and when they are not the same, continue with the rest of the code.

How would I go about doing this?

Edit: Could somone supply some code that works?

```
BGC = robot.getPixelColor(1200, 300);
 System.out.println(robot.getPixelColor(1200, 300));

        int counter = 1;
    while (counter < 10){
        System.out.println(robot.getPixelColor(1200, 300));
        if (BGC == robot.getPixelColor(1200, 300)){
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Colors Match");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Colors Dont Match");
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

This code produces this result the result of Colors Dont Match, along with the colors that clearly do match... Help ._.

Comment: this is a very odd way of doing things.

Comment: Can you show us what you have?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=16400&tstart=0

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/216988/java-code-to-capture-your-screen-as-image

Here are two links describing how to make a screen capture in Java and save it as a BufferedImage.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

Here's the documentation for the BufferedImage class

So what you wanna do is something like:

1. run program
2. take screenshot
3. check RGB-value with some method described in the documentation
4. Compare to old value, is it the same? If it is, go back to 2, else go to 5
5. Rest of program

However I'm not sure if this is what you should want to do. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the robot class (getPixelColor(x,y)) to check the pixel color? but as mentioned before not sure this is how you should be going about it.